# Magento jQuery generate URL

Tags: jquery, magento, url

There it is http://www.parcodesign.com.br, a magento e-commerce. On the footer links, like "Sobre", or "Onde Comprar", "FAQ", "Ajuda", "Informações de Entrega", any of these, when clicked, it triggers a javascript function. This one:

```
function abreInfo(id) {
  jQuery("#infoShow").slideDown('fast', function () {
    jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#infoShow").offset().top -120 }, 200);
      jQuery("#infoShow>section").load("info/" + id + ".phtml", function () {
    });
  });
}
```

The id is taken from each link. It is working fine to show the content, but what I'm searching and trying to do now is to generate a exclusive URL for each of these links. In a way that when the link is clicked, it generates a new URL on the browsers URL box, and than making it able to be copied and accessed from a direct link. Unfortunately, for what I've already searched, no highlights for solutions.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the hyperlinks to have an anchor tag.

```
<a href="#sobre" onclick="return javascript:abreInfo('sobre');">Sobre a Parco</a>
```

This will allow you to have hyperlinks like http://www.parcodesign.com.br/#sobre

Then you will need to have a javascript function which picks up the #tag and handles accordingly. Something like the following;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
           var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
           if(hash != '') {
                abreInfo(hash);
           }

      });
</script>
```

Why don't you create new pages for this content though and just have a normal link to the content. Users without javascript cannot access this content nor can a search engine with your current ajax based implementation.

Comment: Ashley, this is it! Just PERFECT! Thanks for the precautions comments too, I will take those to think about.